# obfuscate real coordinates

Tags: leaflet, openlayers, wms, tiles, vector-tiles

Due to copyrights I cannot deliver some POIs as plain vector data using GeoJSON in Leaflet or OpenLayers. I'm therefor looking for some kind of sane obfuscation, to make it harder for normal users to get to the coordinates.

- Creating a new map projection might not be a good solution, since the webmapping library has to contain the code to reproject to the map's CRS.
- MVT maybe a better solution. Of course the original coordinates still could be reversed, albeit with greater effort.
- Seems like the most secure solution is to precalculate the POIs as raster tiles with a WMS(T) (of course with the map icons). Interactivity would come via UTFgrid.
- I also was thinking about SVG or local leaflet x-y coordinates. Here reverse engineering is still possible, but the effort increases extremely.

Anyone with a better idea?

Comment: you need to go to a higher level, create a username/password/token for users of the site, have your data in a database with a encoder example https://www.danstools.com/javascript-obfuscate/

Comment: @Mapperz Thanks for your answer, but username/password/token doesn't protect the coordinates (LAT/LON, X/Y) from being visible to the user. Also Javascript obfuscating is inefficient nowadays. There are tons of addons for FX and Chrome or website to decrypt it the easy way. obfuscating works nice for variable names (make the code less readable), but it doesn't work well for floats, like coordinates are.

Comment: I just can't see how it is possible to obfuscate coordinates at all if the end result is to display on a georeferenced map.   A WMS gives a single image, so if you have an input point dataset, you style it according to some symbology you choose, and you get an image which has lots of points on it.  It doesn't hide the location of the points, but you can make it so the user can't query the points for additional information, and they don't get the data.

Comment: If you want some querying you can enable that in WMS , but you can decide what data comes back.  If you want to do clustering, and different styles at different scales, you can do that in WMS, and you can restrict the scales at which the maps display too.

Comment: @nmtoken Of course it's possible to analyze the shape of the rendered mapicon with object recognition (or AI) to guess back the coordinate. However, I think that the effort is so high that the owner of the copyright would accept this way of publishing his dataset. My main problem is that I can't provide the coordinates as an easily readable or easily processable vector data set.

Sure, clustering is easy, I did it in PostGIS before. Mouseover is possible by UTFgrid and other information work via GetFeatureInfo.

Comment: I know projects that needed this kind of obfuscation for coordinates. They solved it by only delivering the data on the base of a regular raster (like 1km). This way, of course you don´t have an exact position anymore.

Comment: @Matte I need them at a high resolution. So I think, I'll need to go by raster...